# In topology: Is there a special terminology for a map that is "almost'' a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, terminology

By "almost" I mean that it can be slightly perturbed within a given fixed compact domain to obtain a homeomorphism from that domain to its image.

To be more precise:

Let a compact topological space $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and let a map $f:U\to M$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists homeomorphism $f_\epsilon:U\to V$ (continuous function with continuous inverse) between $U$ and $V$ for some $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\|f(x)-f_\epsilon(x)\|_2<\epsilon \text{ for all } x \in U. \tag{1}
$$

Examples:

- a constant map from cube  $x \in [0,1]^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, $f(x): x \mapsto (0,0,0)$  **is** almost homeomorphism on the cube. Indeed, for any $\epsilon$ one can introduce $f_\epsilon(x): x \mapsto  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \epsilon( x_1, x_2, x_3)$ which is a homeomorphism, and (1) is satisfied.
- a function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$,  $f(x):x^2$ is not almost homeomorphism on $[-1, 1]$, since there is no inverse map for $x=0$.

In one dimension, I presume, a function is almost homeomorphism if and only if it is  monotonic, but I'm not familiar with the notion of monotonic in higher dimensions.

Comment: Monotonic, not monotonous!

Comment: @KCd thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is "near homeomorphism".